# Why won't this cookie set?

Tags: javascript, cookies

The goal of this code is to set a cookie for the background color of the page. I don't understand why the cookie won't set.

```
<select id="ddlTheme" onchange="setColorCookie()">
    <option value="Select Color">Select Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    if(document.cookie.length != 0) {
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
        document.getElementById("ddlTheme").value = nameValueArray[1];
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = nameValueArray[1];
        console.log("Window onload happened sir!");
    }
}
function setColorCookie() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("ddlTheme").value;
    if (selectedValue != "Select Color") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedValue;
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "color=" + selectedValue + ";" + expires;
        console.log("Set cookie");
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `setColorCookie()` function you have a variable `exdays` that is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. Even though I have replaced exdays with the number 30, it still won't work.

Comment: I added ( var exdays = 1) to your code and the cookie was successfully added once I selected a color from the select input. Can I see how you defined exdays?

Comment: I just realized my problem. Chrome won't set cookies for local files. Sorry for the confusion.